# javascript not working to create divs inside of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create 10 divs when a button is clicked, however nothing is happening. I think the issue is with my javascript, but nothing is shown in the console. What am I doing wrong? And what can I do to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Space Invaders
        </title>
        <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">               </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <div id="startbtn"><br />Start Game
        </div>
        <br />
        <center>
        <div id="game" onClick = 'buttonClick'>
        </div>
        <div id="game2">
        </div>
        </center>
        <div id="titlepage">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var row1 = [];
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#startbtn').click(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i<9; i++)
    {
        row1[i] = document.createElement('div');
        row1[i].className = 'grid';
        document.getElementById('game').appendChild(row1[i]);
    }   
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#startbtn
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: auto;
}
#game 
{ 
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
}
#game2
{ 
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
}
.grid 
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. You can't see the added DIVs because `#game` has `display: none`.

Comment: @Barmar if you added that as an answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unhide the `game` DIV:

```
$('#startbtn').click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i<9; i++) {
        row1[i] = document.createElement('div');
        row1[i].className = 'grid';
        document.getElementById('game').appendChild(row1[i]);
    }   
    $("#game").show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8wUmM/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Working example:
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JQUVA/2/)

why dont you use jquery to create DOM element and append?

```
var row1 = [];
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#startbtn').click(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i<9; i++)
    {
       var div = $("<div>").addClass("grid");
       div.appendTo($("#game"));
    }
    $("#game").show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#game 
{ 
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You're not specifying the class of the new DIVs. Other than that, it's equivalent to the original code, so I don't see how it could fix whatever problem he has.